How to find the tangent when converting from 2D angles to Spherical to Cartesian coordinates?
I am making a spherical/ball-in-socket joint, and I want to limit the movement of the bodies relative to each other.
The limit is defined as 2 angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which make a 2D rectangle.

I find point $A$ by using the relative angle of the two bodies. Then I find $\theta$ which the length from the origin to point $A$ on the rectangle and the maximum angle the bodies can misalign from each other.
$\theta$ together with the angle of the line around origin give me point $A$ in spherical coordinates, which I can then convert into Cartesian coordinates and draw them in 3D space.
This is the shape the rectangle with $a=\pi/2$ and $b=0.5$ makes in 3D:



When the bodies' relative angle exceeds $A$, I apply a rotational correction to put them back within the limit. To do that I must find the axis along which to rotate, illustrated in blue. This axis is tangent to the sphere and perpendicular to the normal of the point, illustrated in green.
Currently I am finding this tangent by converting $D$ and $E$ to spherical, then cartesian coordinates and subtracting them. This somewhat works, but is not entirely accurate, and can get unstable due to floating point precision.
I am hoping there is an analytical solution to find this correction axis/tangent.
